# Ngrx Angular - Detected unserializable action at simple object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

i don't get why ngrx pop this error while i'm trying to send to my api a simple object, could you give me some advice about ngrx and the reason why it refuse to serialize my object ?

I tried to put `strictActionSerializability` to `false` , no error but no object sent to my api...

**Error  :**

> Error: Detected unserializable action at "createdPath"

**How i call my action :**

```
   this.storePath.dispatch(PathActions.createPath({ createdPath }));
```

**In actions.ts file :**

```
export const createPath = createAction('[BOT/GROUP] CREATE PATH', props<{ createdPath: Path }>());
```

**And my effect :**

```
createPath$ = createEffect(() =>
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(PathActions.createPath),
  map(action => action.createdPath),
  exhaustMap((createdPath: Path) =>
    this.pathService.createPath(createdPath).pipe(
      map(createdPath => PathActions.createPathSuccess({ createdPath })),
      catchError(error => of(PathActions.createPathFailure({ error }))))
  )
 )
);
```

**My object sent as JSON :**

```
{
"monsterLevel": [],
"monsterQuantity": [],
"monsterCapture": [],
"pathAction": [
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "fightAction": {
                    "isAlone": false
                }
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "moveAction": {
                    "direction": [
                        "Right",
                        "Bottom"
                    ],
                    "toGoBank": false,
                    "toBackBank": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "mapPos": "-14;-53"
    },
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "fightAction": {
                    "isAlone": false
                }
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "moveAction": {
                    "direction": [
                        "Top",
                        "Right"
                    ],
                    "toGoBank": false,
                    "toBackBank": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "mapPos": "-14;-52"
    },
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "fightAction": {
                    "isAlone": false
                }
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "moveAction": {
                    "direction": [
                        "Top",
                        "Left"
                    ],
                    "toGoBank": false,
                    "toBackBank": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "mapPos": "-13;-52"
    },
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "fightAction": {
                    "isAlone": false
                }
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "moveAction": {
                    "direction": [
                        "Left",
                        "Bottom"
                    ],
                    "toGoBank": false,
                    "toBackBank": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "mapPos": "-13;-53"
    },
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "moveAction": {
                    "direction": [
                        "Bottom"
                    ],
                    "toGoBank": true,
                    "toBackBank": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "mapPos": "-14;-51"
    },
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "moveAction": {
                    "direction": [
                        "Bottom"
                    ],
                    "toGoBank": true,
                    "toBackBank": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "mapPos": "-14;-50"
    },
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "moveAction": {
                    "direction": [
                        "Bottom"
                    ],
                    "toGoBank": true,
                    "toBackBank": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "mapPos": "-14;-49"
    },
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "moveAction": {
                    "direction": [
                        "Bottom"
                    ],
                    "toGoBank": true,
                    "toBackBank": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "mapPos": "-14;-48"
    },
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "moveAction": {
                    "cellId": 150,
                    "toGoBank": true,
                    "toBackBank": false
                }
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "zaapAction": {
                    "destination": "-32,-58",
                    "zaapId": 1,
                    "toBackBank": false,
                    "toGoBank": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "mapPos": "-14;-47"
    }
],
"name": "feef",
"type": 0,
"monsterQuantityMin": 0,
"monsterQuantityMax": 8,
"groupLevelMin": 0,
"groupLevelMax": 999,
"maxPod": 51,
"leaderBank": true
}
```

**Class used:**

```
export class Path {
  name: string;
  type: number; /* 0 fight , 1 gather */
  maxPod: number=80;
  monsterQuantityMin: number =0;
  monsterQuantityMax: number =8;
  groupLevelMin: number =0;
  groupLevelMax: number=9999;
  isCapture: boolean =false;
  leaderBank: boolean = false;
  captureItem: number;
  monsterLevel?: SpecificMonsterLevel[];
  monsterQuantity?: SpecificMonsterQuantity[];
  monsterCapture?: CaptureMonsterQuantity[];
  pathAction: PathAction[];
}
```

have a good day, and thanks for your help !

Comment: can't reproduce - see [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktz9cx).

Comment: You are using it as a json object maybe my problem come from my Path class ? 
PS : i edited my post to add the class i use

Comment: Sorry, I'm slow this morning...stackblitz is now a repoduction, forgot to turn on checks. Yes, seem to be due to class...I would suggest adding a serialize method to the Path class

Comment: Np np  ;) i'll try it , maybe using a custome serializer on ngrx would help ?

Comment: Separation of concerns...I don't think it would ever be the responsibility of ngrx to serialize what is being passed into the actions. People will alway try to pass weird things..like components.

Comment: With your solution actually i'm reaching my createPathAction but  the effects is still not triggered, thanks for your help i'm still trying to correct this

Comment: Don't forget `EffectsModule.forRoot([ApiEffects])/ EffectsModule.forFeature([ApiEffects])` to activate them

Comment: I did,  all my others store works exept this one ...

Comment: my example didn't bother with the reducer but this would need to be implemented and `NgrxStoreModule` imported into `AppModule`

Comment: I made it work  ! Just missing a prop on my object  this thing make it worked : 
{ createdPath: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(createdPath)) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure data class object you can use

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product))
```

Otherwise, I suggest adding a `toJSON()` serialization method (which is automatically used by JSON.stringify)

```
public class Foo{
    private _bar:string;

    constructor(){ this._bar='Baz'; }

    get bar():string{return this._bar}

    toJSON() {
      return {bar: _bar};
    }

    static fromJSON(json) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Reference - [Angular 2 (or 4) object serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407491)

Comment: Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew Allen resolved my issue  by stringify and re parse my object :

```
  this.storePath.dispatch(PathActions.createPath({ createdPath: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(createdPath)) }));
```

Comment: perfect! the best solution